# Centering element vertically on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have problem problem with centering element on mobile devices, when height decreases, top content is hidden but on desktop is okey. Please see below link for see problem in screenshot

[Desktop version](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/9/8f61635b24ebcaea779fdcfed19283a6-full.png)

[Mobile version](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/9/5cdeea7f4e7d76ff9ca48b574ba63367-full.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-section">
    <div class="modal-area">
      <div class="header">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur 
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <div class="element">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: oldlace;
  color: #2F2F2F;
  z-index: 99999;
  overflow: auto;
}
.items {
  display: flex;  
  margin: 20px 0;
  justify-content: center;
}
.element {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
}
.img {
    height: 150px;
}
```

example code

https://jsfiddle.net/twzud65n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have some elements that don't quite do something and have no styling applied to fit in. What is the suppose of `modal-section`?

Because you have `position: fixed` on your modal, you need to tell its children to not overflow their parent. `width: 100%` does that, `height: auto` means it can scale as much as needed allowing to scroll.

Try this:

```
.modal-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `justify-content: center` which is centering your element (even if it's overflowing). You can turn it off and add `margin:auto` to `.modal-section`.

Example

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: oldlace;
  color: #2F2F2F;
  z-index: 99999;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-section {
  margin: auto;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0;
  justify-content: center;
}
.element {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
}
.img {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-section">
    <div class="modal-area">
      <div class="header">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur 
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <div class="element">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still problem, little changes but no show all content again

Comment: I've posted example now. I can see upper 'Lorem ipsum' well.

Comment: you add modal-content class. where i mus add this ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed, meant to be `.modal-section`.